# Output is 5 5 6 7 8 9 explain how?

Tags: c, recursion

Can someone please explain how this recursion is working in the following code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

func(int x)
{

    if(x>5) 
    func(--x);

    printf("%d",x);
}

int main(void)
{

func(10);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: It works by having the function call it self repeatedly

Comment: How does this compile? Are you using Turbo C?

Comment: No. I am running it on eclipse ide

Comment: @EdwardKarak Not sure why you're casting asparagus about Turbo C.  The posted code compiles fine for me, using a modern compiler.  (I might have expected a warning about implicit `int` on `func`.)

Comment: @MandarTamboli I'm surprised it prints `5` twice, but other than that it's straightforward.

Comment: @SteveSummit That's exactly what I'm talking about

Comment: @SteveSummit yes that is my question why it prints 5 twice?

Comment: @MandarTamboli The question -- which I'm too lazy to solve this morning -- has to do with the confusing use of the `--` operator.  If this were a conventional recursive function, it would have a straightforward test and recursive call `if(x>5) func(x-1);`, and it wouldn't print 5 twice, and it would be easy to understand.  Figuring out why this confusing, badly-written code prints a confusing result might make a good puzzle (or not), but I don't think it will teach you anything useful, and I'm annoyed at whoever presented it to you.

Comment: @MandarTamboli then you need to add that detail to your question.  As it stands now what you're asking is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The function logic works that way:
If `x` is bigger than 5, the function will be called again with `x` decremented by 1.

In the following line:

```
func(--x);
```

`--x` means that `x` will be decremented by 1 **before** this code line executes, different than `x--` which means `x` will be decremented **after** the line.
When `x` will be equal to 5, it will be printed and then the function will return to the last place it was called from and continue from there, meaning `x` will be printed again with the value it had in the last call, then return again so on and so forth.

So the function will basically print all the numbers from 5 to the given number (if it’s bigger than 5 of course), excluding the given number, since x was decremented before it was printed.

In your case the call `func(10)` will result in the following output:

```
56789
```

Comment: `func(10)` will print from `9`, because `x` was decremented.